# Is this neglected Bay Tree dying? Is it worth saving?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care

I am in New Zealand where it is currently late summer/early fall. I have this tree which has been living in the same pot, unattended, for a number of years.

As you can see in the photos, about half the leaves have been shed leaving a rather sorry looking crown with many bare branches.

[image: tree 1]

[image: tree 2]

In the past 10 days I have added some seaweed fertiliser to the soil, and sprayed the crown with both anti-fungal and insecticide treatments.

Three questions

1. Any idea what is wrong?
2. Is the tree worth saving or is it too far gone?
3. Should I trim off the "dead" branches or leave them to see if they recover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tree doesn't look in great shape, but green leaves means there's life there. You can tell if the twigs are dead by gently scraping the bark with a sharp knife. If you can't see green, they're dead and can be removed. Try with a healthy shrub so you know what you're looking for. If the plant is rootbound, you can try repotting it into a larger container. It's essential that the compost isn't waterlogged. If it is, repot with good quality soil based compost ([John Innes](https://www.rhs.org.uk/soil-composts-mulches/john-innes-compost), for example) and drainage material at the bottom of the container. If all else fails, you could try cutting the stem back to an inch or so and seeing if it reshoots. If that works you should end up with a better shaped plant. Be patient.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Six weeks later and the plant is no better (or worse) - I will follow your advice and continue to be patient